# Swipe stopped working recently on Chrome mobile

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome

I have a swipe function that recently stopped working so and we suspect it's the new update for chrome mobile (not tested on other mobile browsers). The code is still the same. I have tried to search for information if the newest updates contained something that could break the swipe, but no luck. Any others have had issues recently?

I'm using this npm package for the swipe: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-touch

In code:

```
<Swipeable
      onSwipeLeft={this.goToNextSlide}
      onSwipeRight={this.goToPrevSlide} >

      <div className={styles["sliderWrapper"]} style={{ transform: `translateX(${this.state.translateValue}px)`, transition: 'transform ease-out 0.45s' }}> {
        this.state.newsItems.map((item, i) => (this.renderSlide(item, i)))}
      </div>
    </Swipeable>
```